# SO WMD editor javascripts load RoutingError

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, wmd, rails-routing, wmd-editor

I'm sure the answer to this is very straightforward:

I'm trying to use the WMD editor from derobins ([Here](https://github.com/derobins/wmd)) with my rails app (it's the one on SO that I'm using as I type). But for some reason the js files (showdown.js and wmd.js) aren't loading.

In the console I'm getting the errors:

> ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/public/javascripts/wmd")
>   ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/public/javascripts/showdown")

... despite the fact that both files - wmd.js and showdown.js are in [myapp]/public/javascripts.

The readme says to include the files like this:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="showdown.js"></script>
```

... which I tried but this didn't work (for obvious reasons, I think).

So I included them like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/public/javascripts/wmd.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/public/javascripts/showdown.js"></script>
```

I've tried these with `..` at the start (e.g. `src="..public/"`), without the `/`, and with and without the `.js`.

Any help gratefully received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution: changed the includes to

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'showdown' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'wmd' %>
```

But still no idea why it wasn't working before.